# Blank images(say not found) in etalage.js plugin

Tags: javascript

Hi have etalage.js installed in my site(dev site, not link), some images are not found in the the server(they were deleted example img) so i did remove those images(using .remove jquery) when they are not found. The problem is when i remove those images(i think i broke the code needed for etalage in order to work), my plugin is not working properly.

image 1 is before i remove "blank" images(blank refering to not found in my server)
[image: Before using .remove()]

image when i USED .remove()
[image]

This is the code when i inspect Source code: 
[image]

Etalage grab that code and transform it to built the right structure(this is the code when i inspect developer tool in google:
[image]

How can i remove those images before etalage.js build that structure?

P.S. the right think is not printing those images in the html, but they dont want to do that(lazyness?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe re-call the etalage function after running your remove code will solve that

Comment: an actual code sample would be useful. Maybe create one on jsfiddle?

Comment: Instead of removing, how about setting the source to a placeholder "no img" image, eg. example.com/no-img.jpg

Comment: Thanks @FajryHamzah, it works if i remove first and the call etalage!

tested in http://jaciel.byethost7.com/etalage.html

I deleted image 1 and 5 on purpose from my server,

Comment: Thanks @yezzz, can't do that, i NEED to remove it from sight XD